# What happens when we scale the kubernetes deployment and change one of the pod or container configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

When i scale the application by creating deployment .Let's say i am running nginx service on 3 cluster.
Nginx is running in containers in multiple pods .
If i change nginx configuration in one of the pod ,does it propagate to all the nodes and pods because it is running in cluster and scaled.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the configuration? Or better to ask where do you store this configuration? In ConfigMap?

Comment: "on 3 cluster" do you mean "on 3 nodes"?

Answer (score 0):

> does it propagate to all the nodes and pods because it is running in
>   cluster and scaled.

No. Only when you change the deployment yaml. Then it re-creates pods 1 by 1 with the new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a few more things to what was already said. First of all you are even not supposed to do any changes to `Pods` which are managed let's say by `ReplicaSet`, `ReplicationController` or `Deployment`. This are objects which provide additional abstraction layer and it is their responsibility to ensure that there are given number of `Pods` of a certain kind running in your **kubernetes cluster**.
It doesn't matter how many nodes your cluster consists of as mentioned controllers span across all nodes in the cluster.

Changes made in a single `Pod` will not only not propagate to other `Pods` but may be easily lost if such newly created `Pod` with changed configuration crashes.

Remember that one of the tasks of the `Deployment` is to make sure that certain number of `Pods` of a given type ( specified in a `Pod` `template` section of the `Deployment` ) are always up and running. When your manually reconfigured `Pod` goes down then your `Deployment` (actually `ReplicaSet` created by the `Deployment`) acts behind the scenes and recreates such `Pod`. But how does it recreate it ? Does it take into consideration changes introduced by you to such `Pod` ? Of course not, it will recreate it based on the `template` it is given in the `Deployment`.

If you want to make changes in your `Pods` one by one **kubernetes** allows you to do so by providing so called [**rolling update**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) mechanism. 
[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/) you can read about old-fashioned approach using **ReplicationController** which is not used any more as it is replaced by `Deployments` and `ReplicaSets` but I think it's still worth reading just to grasp the concept.
Currently **Deployment** is the way to go. About updating a `Deployment` you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment). Note that the default update strategy is `RollingUpdate` which ensures that changes are not applied to all Pods at once but one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So far what i understood that whatever (creating pods and assigning it to different nodes ) we are publishing must not be changed , whenever any new changes introduced in the container image ,what should i do in that case ? Do i need to build new image then create new deployments and then replicas  with new version?

Comment: You can update your `Deployment` e.g. by applying edited yaml file in which you set newer version of your image. Yes, you should build new image but you don't have to create new deployment. You can update the existing one. The `Deployment` controller will automatically create new replicaset (as it is managed by deployment, so you don't have to create it manually either) and will update your `Pods` one after another if the default update strategy is used (alternative is: `Recreate` which deletes all current `Pods` and then recreates them).